# webscraping with selenium to click a button and grab everything

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping

I have been working on this scraper for a while and I think it could be improved but I'm not sure where to go from here.

The initial scraper looks like this and I believe it does everything I need it to do:

```
                                                                                                                                                        
url = "https://matrix.heartlandmls.com/Matrix/Public/Portal.aspx?L=1&k=990316X949Z&p=DE-74613894-421"   

h_table = []
driver = webdriver.Firefox()
driver.get(url)
driver.find_element_by_xpath("/html/body/form/div[3]/div/div/div[5]/div[3]/span[2]/div/div/div[2]/div[1]/div/div/div[2]/div[2]/div[1]/span/a").click()
time.sleep(10)
i = 200
while i > 0:
    h_table.append(driver.find_element_by_id("wrapperTable").text)
    driver.find_element_by_xpath("/html/body/form/div[3]/div/div/div[5]/div[2]/div/div[1]/div/div/span/ul/li[2]/a").click()
    time.sleep(10)
    i -= 1
```

this outputs everything into a table which i can clean up

```
['210 Sitter Street\nPleasant Hill, MO 64080\nMLS#:2178982\nMap\n$15,000\nSold\n4Bedrms\n2Full Bath(s)\n0Half Bath(s)\n1,848Sqft\nBuilt in1950\n0.27Acres\nSingle Family\n1 / 10\nThis Home sits on a level, treed, and nice .279 acre sizeable double lot. The property per taxes, is identified as a Single Family Home however it has 2 separate utility meters and 2 living spaces, each with 2 bedrooms and 1 full bath and laundry areas, and was utilized as a Duplex for Rental income for 2 units. This property is a CASH ONLY sale and is being sold "In It\'s Present Condition". Home and detached garage are in need of repair OR would be a candidate for a tear down and complete rebuild on the lot.\nAbout 210 Sitter Street, Pleasant Hill, MO 64080\nDirections:I-70 to 7 Hwy, to Broadway, to Sitter St, to property.\nGeneral Description\nMLS Number\n2178982\nCounty\nCass\nCity\nPleasant Hill\nSub Div\nWalkers & Sitlers\nType\nSingle Family\nFloor Plan Description\nRanch\nBdrms\n4\nBaths Full\n2\nBaths Half\n0\nAge Description\n51-75 Years\nYear Built\n1950\nSqft Main\n1848\nSQFT MAIN SOURCE\nPublic Record\nBelow Grade Finished Sq Ft\n0\nBelow Grade Finished Sq Ft Source\nPublic Record\nSqft\n1848\nLot Size\n12,155\nAcres\n0.27\nSchools E\nPleasant Hill Prim\nSchools M\nPleasant Hill\nSchools H\nPleasant Hill\nSchool District\nPleasant Hill\nLegal Description\nWALKER & SITLERS LOT 47 & 48 BLK 5\nS Terms\nCash\nInterior Features\nFireplace?\nY\nFireplace Description\nLiving Room, Wood Burning\nBasement\nN\nBasement Description\nBlock, Crawl Space\nDining Area Description\nEat-In Kitchen\nUtility Room\nMultiple, Main Level\nInterior Features\nFixer Up\nRooms\nBathroom Full\nLevel 1\n2nd Full Bath\nLevel 1\nMaster Bedroom\nLevel 1\nSecond Bedroom\nLevel 1\nMaster BR- 2nd\nLevel 1\nFourth Bedroom\nLevel 1\nKitchen\nLevel 1\nKitchen- 2nd\nLevel 1\nLiving Room\nLevel 1\nFamily Rm- 2nd\nLevel 1\nExterior / Construction\nGarage/Parking?\nY\nGarage/Parking #\n2\nGarage Description\nDetached, Front Entry\nConstruction\nFrame\nArchitecture\nTraditional\nRoof\nComposition\nLot Description\nCity Limits, City Lot, Level, Treed\nIn Floodplain\nNo\nInside City Limits\nYes\nStreet Maintenance\nPub Maint, Paved\nExterior Features\nFixer Up\nUtility Information\nCentral Air\nY\nHeat\nForced Air Gas\nCool\nCentral Electric, Window Unit(s)\nWater\nCity/Public\nSewer\nCity/Public\nFinancial Information\nS Terms\nCash\nHoa Amount\n$0\nTax\n$1,066\nSpecial Tax\n$0\nTotal Tax\n$1,066\nExclusions\nEntire Property\nType Of Ownership\nPrivate\nWill Sell\nCash\nAssessment & Tax\nAssessment Year\n2019\n2018\n2017\nAssessed Value - Total\n$17,240\n$15,380\n$15,380\nAssessed Value - Land\n$2,400\n$1,920\n$1,920\nAssessed Value - Improved\n$14,840\n$13,460\n$13,460\nYOY Change ($)\n$1,860\n$\nYOY Change (%)\n12%\n0%\nTax Year\n2019\n2018\n2017\nTotal Tax\n$1,178.32\n$1,065.64\n$1,064.30\nYOY Change ($)\n$113\n$1\nYOY Change (%)\n11%\n0%\nNotes for you and your agent\nAdd Note\nMap data ©2020\nTerms of Use\nReport a map error\nMap\n200 ft \nParcel Disclaimer'
```

however, I had seen some other examples with WebDriverWait, but so far I have been unsuccessful, I think it would greatly speed up the scraper, here's the code I wrote

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

url = "https://matrix.heartlandmls.com/Matrix/Public/Portal.aspx?L=1&k=990316X949Z&p=DE-74613894-421"
h_table = []
xpath = '/html/body/form/div[3]/div/div/div[5]/div[2]/div/div[1]/div/div/span/ul/li[2]/a'
driver = webdriver.Firefox()
driver.get(url)
driver.find_element_by_xpath("/html/body/form/div[3]/div/div/div[5]/div[3]/span[2]/div/div/div[2]/div[1]/div/div/div[2]/div[2]/div[1]/span/a").click()
time.sleep(10)
while True:
    button = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("/html/body/form/div[3]/div/div/div[5]/div[2]/div/div[1]/div/div/span/ul/li[2]/a")
    if len(button) < 1:
        print('done')
        break
    else:
        h_table.append(driver.find_element_by_id("wrapperTable").text)
        WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, 'xpath'))).click()
```

this seems to give all the results, but it gives duplicates and I couldn't stop it without a keyboard interrupt

```
calling len(h_table) = 258, where it should be 200
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if the length of your list is the problem, why not using :

```
    if len(h_table) >= 200:
        print("done")
        break
```

Comment: that might be the way to go, and just catch the outliers, something weird is happening, there are 200 entries, it got to the last one by entry 208, so it grabbed some duplicates early on, then it repeated the last entry until I interrupted it.maybe I need to set the wait parameter higher and the length parameter you suggested